# How to disable SELinux in Android 8.1 Oreo?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source, init, selinux

I want to disable SELinux at boot time for Android Oreo 8.1. I want to execute a script at boot in init.rc file. But it returns this error at boot:

*does not have a SELinux domain defined*

I've already defined enforcing=0 and androidboot.selinux=permissive in my kernel cmdline in BoardConfig.mk

I have the following in my init.rc file:

```
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    bootchart stop
    exec - system system -- /system/bin/sh /system/bin/batteryless.sh
```

Comment: First, can you run "adb shell getenforce" to confirm that you've actually set to permissive correctly?

Comment: Even in permissive mode you must define every new domain. See following page to do so: https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy#label_new_services_and_address_denials
Permissive mode allows you to keep the SELinux rules empty though.

Comment: android permanently disable selinux